# Doctrine2: OneToMany on mapped superclass

Tags: doctrine-orm, relationship, class-table-inheritance, mappedsuperclass

My DB structure is as follows:

work:

- [CTI](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) table **Work**
- [MappedSuperclass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) table **AbstractImageWork** which extends **Work**
- final table **PhotoWork** which extends **AbstractImageWork**

comment:

- [MappedSuperclass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) table **Comment**
- final table **WorkComment** which extends **Comment**

**WorkComment** has a ManyToOne relation to **Work**:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity="Work", inversedBy="comments")
```

**Work** has a OneToMany relation to **WorkComment**:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity="WorkComment", mappedBy="work")
```

The problem is that Doctrine gives me this error while updating the schema:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
It is illegal to put an inverse side one-to-many or many-to-many association on
mapped superclass 'Acme\...\AbstractImageWork#comments'.
```

I guess this has something to do with the MappedSuperclass **AbstractImageWork** stuck in the middle between **Work** and **PhotoWork**, but I didn't actually put this relation on the MappedSuperclass, but on the CTI table.. so why will Doctrine behave like this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In some cases, when you have such error when inherit from the class that is tagged as `@ORM\MappedSuperclass`, try to change your properties access level from **private** to **protected**

Comment: Well, strangely, this solution is not working for me. I’m running into the (almost exact) same issue and all my entities’ properties are already “protected”. I tried changing them to “public” to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only). **This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all.** Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped superclass is only used in exactly one entity at the moment. For further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance features have to be used.

Check it out here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

In others cases happens when you declare `@ORM\Entity` in an abstract superior class instead of `@ORM\MappedSuperclass`