# Inverse side of one-to-many relation on mapped superclass - Doctrine ORM

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I am trying to update my database schema but I am getting following error:

```
  [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                                        
  It is illegal to put an inverse side one-to-many or many-to-many association on mapped superclass 'AppBundle\Entity\ListContent#attachments'.
```

I have following entity hierarchy:

`Content` entity is concrete class for Single table inheritance where I store all of my content eg. `Page`, `Blog`, etc.

In `Content` entity I have `one-to-many` relation to `Attachment` entity like this:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection|Attachment
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Attachment", mappedBy="content")
 */
protected $attachments;
```

and of course on `Attachment` entity I have:

```
/**
 * @var Content
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Content", inversedBy="attachments")
 */
private $content;
```

Some of STI entities extends `Content` entity but some of them extends abstract `ListContent` which is defined as `mapped superclass` and has some additional fields.

I want to be able to access `attachments` either from entities which extends `Content` and also entities which extends `ListContent` so I've put `one-to-may` association to `Content` entity since `ListContent` is extending it.

i was looking for solution but I can only find this one [Doctrine2: OneToMany on mapped superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124225/doctrine2-onetomany-on-mapped-superclass) and it is not appropriate for me since I don't want to define relationship on my `ListContent`.

Does anyone came across this issue? How did you resolve it?

Comment: First thing I would try is changing the private $content to protected, second would be to include the joinColumn on the ManyToOne relationship like so: `@JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")`. See more here [link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work. Problem occurs on abstract class `ListContent` which extends `Content`. Field `attachments` is defined on `Content` class but the error is mentioning `ListContent`... Any idea?

Comment: @Cockootec Did you ever find a solution to this?